# Расположение элементов при выравнивании по центру

Tags: css3, html, css

Расположил элементы по центру, это меню и сам блок с содержимым, потом добавил еще элементы, они служат как верх и низ блока с содержимым, но при выравнивании, они ушли вниз (под блок с содержимым), а не вверх, тем самым, при прокрутке содержимого с фиксированной высотой, вверх и низ не остаются на месте, а крутятся с ним же, плюс полоса прокрутки выше встала...

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="menu">
        меню
    </div>
    <div class="top">вверх</div>
        <div class="content">
            блок с содержимым
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">низ</div>
    </div>
</div>

.main {
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
.menu {
    width: 150px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 50px 0px -35px;
}
.content {
    width: 650px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 35px 0px 0px 15px;
    padding: 65px 0px 15px 30px;
    overflow: auto;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
.top {
    width: 650px;
    margin: -65px 0px 0px -35px;
    padding: 10px 15px 10px 25px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
.bottom {
    width: 650px;
    margin: 500px 0px 0px -35px;
    padding: 10px 15px 10px 25px;
```

Answer (score 1):

после float нужно обнулять свойством clear:both;
поставь после последнего блока который на float <div style="clear:both;"></div>

Comment: не помогло

Comment: получилось с position: fixed; z-index: 2;